# How should I value personal use television for donation?

Tags: united-states, donation, depreciation

Given an LCD television using primarily for personal use, if I were to donate it what would the donation value be?

I assumed that I should take straight-line depreciation over its useful life?
IRS says 5-years for computer equipment, but I couldn't find an IRS guideline for TV's. Googling turning up a non-IRS page suggesting 12-year for color TVs.

Comment: My understanding is that you have to get a receipt stating the value from the organization you donate it to. You can't just donate stuff and decide the value.

Comment: @DJClayworth Depends how interested the organization is in basic courtesy. In my experience (places like Goodwill), they only give you a detailed receipt about 10% of the time. Usually, they will either not offer anything at all (you have to ask) or they give you blank one and you have to fill it out on your own. Which is probably illegal on their part, but nobody seems to care.

Comment: How someone who makes enough money for itemized deductions to be worthwhile (vs the standard deduction) thinks it makes sense to spend their time trying to save a few bucks on taxes is beyond me...

Comment: @R.. how much is your time worth that you spent it writing that comment, which earned you not even a few bucks?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Second this... Goodwill always asks if I want a receipt and I usually say no, but the one time I had a lot of stuff and said yes they just gave me a blank one with "guidelines" on how to value stuff.  I thought the whole purpose of the receipt is that I don't have to just make stuff up about what I think I donated is worth and have actual proof of what I donated!

Comment: It earned me Internet Points (tm) though! ;-) Anyway the point was that while it makes sense to deduct actual significant cash (or major property like vehicles, boats, land, buildings, etc.) donations, it seems pretty silly to try to deduct a used TV.

Comment: Comments don't earn you any Magic Internet Points @R..

Comment: @R.. A deduction with a fair market value of $2000 on my schedule A will save me ~$600 at my effective tax rate of 30%

Comment: How is a used TV worth $2000? More like $200.

Comment: @R.. right so that's perhaps why you didn't understand my question. This particular used TV is worth about $2000

Comment: I would think the IRS would find it dubious to claim a used TV is worth $2000 even if you paid several thousand for it new. Anyway see the good existing answers on documenting fair market value.

Comment: @R.. They can call it dubious if they like. It is worth that much according to Amazon/EBay and worth more in a straight-line depreciate method (which is why I'm asking... the value is not immaterial)

Comment: I smell an audit coming if you stick with that valuation for a television...

Comment: @DanielAnderson Maybe, but that doesn't make the valuation inaccurate. The risk of any valuation is whether the audit risk is worth it I think.... If the IRS were to look up the value of the item they'd come to the same conclusion.... which is why I want to make sure I'm using the method they suggest.

Comment: Wow...You give the IRS much more credit than I *ever* would! (grin)  Keep in mind that there's a HUGE difference between what people are trying to sell things for and what anyone is actually willing to **pay**.  Maybe there are sellers with listings offering it that for your stated amount, or better yet, they're using an inflated MSRP to make their "sale" price look better.  Either way, a price tag is different from a completed sale at the price you're stating.  Looking at eBay, I see quite a few where the price is "$2,500 or best offer", with no takers.  Caution if you use those prices!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[IRS Pub 561](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p561/index.html) says you have to use fair market value.  You cannot simply use a depreciated value.

You should attempt to determine what people normally pay for comparable items, and be prepared to defend your determination with evidence in the event of an audit.

Answer (score 16):

The usual lazy recommendation: See what similar objects, in similar condition, of similar age, have sold for recently on eBay. That establishes a fair market value by directly polling the market.

Comment: Or craigslist, though that has the problem that you will only see prices for sales that didn't happen (which may indicate the prices are too high).

Answer (score 6):

Is it a tube television, digital, analog, what?  Tube televisions are no longer made in (or imported to) the U.S., and if it's an analog set then it would require a digital converter just for anyone to use it for watching broadcast signals, since analog television signals are gone and have been replaced by DTV.  That makes all the difference in the world as far as valuation.  If it doesn't have resale value to begin with then I doubt you can put a real value on it for donation purposes.

Comment: To your point, nowadays tube TVs may have a negative value since it oftentimes costs money to get rid of them. (The garbage trucks won't take them off the curb anymore- you have to pay to drop them off at a recycling center.)

Comment: True, since tube televisions contain mercury, they have to be disposed of as hazardous waste.  Good point.  Upvote on your comment!

Comment: I don't believe CRT tubes have mercury in them. Fluorescent bulbs do, but not CRT tubes.

Comment: It's an LCD TV that's a ~4 years old.

Comment: @zeta-band, you're correct.  There's no mercury, but quite a bit of lead.  Upvote for the correction!

Comment: A 4-year old LCD?  Depending on size, brand and condition, it might just be nice of you to donate it and not worry about the tax deduction.  Just a thought...

Comment: The OP is donating it either way. So it's just a question of how to value it and whether the valuation obtained will be worth enough of a deduction to justify the effort.

Comment: That was my point, but you put it more succinctly.  Thanks!  Upvote for it!

Comment: Over 4 years old, I know. We are at the point where a tube/crt will not be accepted by most charities. Flat panel have dropped like a rock in price. The 65” Sony I bought in ‘12 for $2000 can be bought new for under $700.

Answer (score 1):

I used **TurboTax** last year. It had a section for donations where it figured out the amounts of the IRS approved values for a donation.

You would need to know the size of the television and the current condition it is in.

He's a screenshot - though it's not from the TV section.

[image]

https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Taxes-101/Video--How-to-Estimate-the-Value-of-Clothing-for-IRS-Deductions/INF13870.html+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

TurboTax offers a free online tool called [ItsDeductible](https://turbotax.intuit.com/personal-taxes/itsdeductible) that does the same thing (though I haven't tried it).

Unfortunately, I don't have the current one with TV's to give you the range of amounts that apply to yours.

--I am not affiliated with TurboTax and did **not** receive it for free for a review.

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE]!  This answer will likely be deleted because it only provides information about a resource for determining the answer, rather than actually answering the question.  Please visit the [Help Center](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.

Comment: @dg99 - Unfortunately, there are more criteria for determining the value, like it's condition and size, which are not in the question. I took the question as "How Can I determine" not "What is the value of the thing in my hand". My answer seems much more helpful to than an exact answer to his specific (unknown) item.

Comment: I wonder how Intuit comes up with their values because they always seem crazy to me. Way more than I would expect to spend buying the item from the same thrift store I donated it to. That said, the highest value for a TV they have is "Television: LCD: 50 inch or larger" which they say is worth as much as $499.

Comment: @stannous - That is crazy - I only paid **$429** for a **55"** a few months ago. It looks like I'm **donating** the old one.